# I know my code works when I run everything on localhost but when i try deploying to heroku i have an issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, server, cors

Access to fetch at 'url' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

i get this issue, i tried doing mode: "no-cors" but it still seems as though my front end cant communicate with my backend server, so i was wondering how i allow access so cors stops restricting access.
Again, my code was 100% fine until i tried deploying my server

when I input into a form the request payload reflects it but it returns undefined

Comment: Have you hardcoded `localhost` into your API requests? Heroku won't understand that.

Comment: `i tried doing mode: "no-cors"` a common misconception about no-cors is that it *bypasses* CORS, which would render CORS useless. Does your frontend issue CORS headers?

Comment: What does your fetch look like?  while developing it's a common error to do URL like `https://localhost:3000/myapi?val=10`  when a more portable version would be just `/myapi?val=10`,  IOW: In your fetch just leave out the Domain.  Otherwise `localhost` is pointing at your computer, and not heroku's.

Comment: thanks guys i figured out what the issue was there, turns out it was throwing a error that made it seem like something else
now im running into a different problem but that'll be fora different post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This URL gives temporary access to CORS servers. You need to navigate to it and click the button "Request temporary access to demo servers." In testing, lasts about 24 hours.

**https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/corsdemo**

If need be, just add the related prefix like so before your service:

**https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com**/https://myservice.com/

(this may not be what you asked for, but could help, the prefix is very useful)